# Taking input and comparing values to that of a multi dimensional array (Java)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, user-input, boolean-operations

```
public class ZooManagement {

    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[][] employeeInfo = {{"bob", "ross"}, {"timmy", "turner"}, {"red","forman"}};

    System.out.println("Welcome to your Zoo Employee Tool!");
    System.out.println("Please enter your employee id.");
    String id = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter your password.");
    String password = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Here's a snippet of the code that I'm working with right now. Basically my goal is to take user input and compare their values for `id` and `password` to that of the values listed in the `employeeInfo[][]` array while using a boolean variable as a flag if a match is found. I'm very new to Java and programming in general so any suggestions would greatly help!

Comment: Since you're new programmer and there isn't response to your question, I've to ask you do you know anything about methods (not necessary) and loops (necessary)?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ZooManagement
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        final String[][] employeeInfo = {{"bob", "ross"}, {"timmy", "turner"}, {"red","forman"}};
        boolean flag = false;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter username:  ");
        String username = scanner.next();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Please enter password:  ");
        String password = scanner.next();
        System.out.println();

        for(int row = 0;  row < employeeInfo.length;  row++)
        {
            for(int column = 0; column < employeeInfo[row].length; column++)
            {
                if(employeeInfo[row][0].equals(username)  &&  employeeInfo[row][1].equals(password))
                {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        } 

        if(flag)
        {
            System.out.print("Successful login");
        } 
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Invalid username or password");
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This actually works perfectly! I adjusted a few minor things for formatting purposes, but the code is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your timely response!

Comment: You are welcome, but I wonder why I was voted down in the first place. Please vote me up since the code worked for you @Big Cat.